# Can we zoom out a image by code, which is been zoomed in by pinch zoom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

The implementation of **pinch zoom** is been done by using `UIScrollView` and putting 'UIImageView` inside it, through following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.delegate = self;
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Then after checking zoomScale scrolling is been enabled as:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
if (scrollView.zoomScale!=1.0) 
{
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
else 
{
    slideShowImageViewScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
}
```

And here is the view that is for zooming in, in scroll view

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
return slideShowImageView;
}
```

Now using timer the image of `UIImageView` is been changed after a time period, by following code:

```
- (void) changeImageSlide
{
    if (imageCounter>=totalNoOfImages-1) 
    {
        imageCounter=0;
    }
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds objectAtIndex:imageCounter]];
    mainSlideShowImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str]];
    [mainSlideShowImageView setTag:[[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds objectAtIndex:imageCounter] intValue]];     
    imageCounter++;
}
```

**Only thing problamatic here is when the next image is loaded that is also, 'zoomed in'**, we want image in normal mode.
Can we achieve it(by coding it for zoom out in our `changeImageSlide` method or any where)?
If yes, then how?
If no, then is there any alternative?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the zoom scale on the scrollview to reset it to 1.0. You could even store zoom levels against images so that it preserves the individual zoom setting per image.

Answer (score 2):

As you load the new image, set the `zoomScale` of the scrollView to 1.0.

```
[slideShowImageViewScrollView setZoomScale:1.0 animated:NO];
```

Comment: Copying other peoples answers is not polite.

Comment: I didn't.  There was no answer when I responded.  I open questions in tabs, so maybe you had answered by the time I got to that tab.  Do you honestly think that I had to copy your answer?  Where is your code snippet anyway?  Did I copy that from you?

Hey, rptwsthi, select Simon's answer as the right one.  I'm not in this for the points.